# Questions about inviting response, dishonesty, uploading image.

Tags: discussion, support, images

Some general questions, please:

(1) I am studying graduate math online, this forum is the *best* place for getting help. If I post a question and if I would like a certain person whom I respected to help with my problem, how do I "invite" him?

(2) If I post a problem for guidance, for those of you who are professors or emeritus professors, would you frown on it and consider it as dishonesty?

(3) I saw a posting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071167/measure-exercise-22-from-folland/1071359#1071359) with what looks like an scanned image of a diagram, how do you do that? Where to find help? (Just the other day I did just that, but the *jpg* image showed up so small in the posting that I was penalized and got two down-votes as a result.)

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: In general, it is not a very good practice to ask several unrelated questions in one post. (This is true both for posts on main and on meta.) You might consider the first two related, but the third one is completely unrelated to the first two questions.

Comment: For the third question you can have a look at questions tagged ([meta-tag:images]) and a link about uploading images is given also in the [tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/images/info).

Comment: The answer to (1) is basically "you can't".

Comment: This seems related to (1): [Comments of the form 'Please look at my question'](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15053/comments-of-the-form-please-look-at-my-question)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : This goes to Najib Idrissi: That would be rather sad, in my opinion. The reason I would like to "invite" certain person is that some members, most likely those teaching profession, undeniably have better skill and patience to explain things to learning students. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @A.Magnus when you come to a community forum, you are allowing **anyone** in the community the opportunity to help you. If this is not what you want, this may not be the best place to ask for help. Also, just because someone is a professor of mathematics doesn't mean they have undeniably better skills and patience at explaining something. They may a geniuses at their craft but horrible at presented it and I have seen that.

Comment: I read OP as wanting to direct questions to a specific individual (who happens to be a math academic), rather than at a "generic math professor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the following picture:

[image]

which you have uploaded in [the first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/938196/revisions) of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938196/when-equality-holds-in-an-inequality), I do not think the problem was that the picture was too small. The problem was mainly that it had a large blank area, so it was scaled to fit the area for the question. If you cut from the picture only the relevant part, it is more readable:

[image]

Feel free to copy the clipped picture to your question, if you think it improves your post. (But I think that the current version, where all the content of the picture was reproduced, does no lack anything after omitting the picture.)

I should point out that:

- This is only relevant to the third part of your question. If you post the question about posting an image as a separate question, I will delete my post here and move it to the new post.
- I am not really sure to which extent this answer the third part of your question, since you did not mention any details. (I had to guess which picture you had problems with.)
- The downvotes did not necessarily come because of the picture. (But it is a reasonable guess.) Another issue with your post is a rather non-descriptive title: *When equality holds in an inequality*. (Although for me this would not be reason enough to downvote, some users might have higher standards.)
- On the other hand, there are some commendable things about your post. (Perhaps deserving an upvote.) You included the source where the question comes from. You explained which part from that book is exactly the place you have problem with.

Comment: Thank you and yes, you have answered my third question exactly! I did not know that you still can retrieve the image. (Next time I will do it better by separating topics into separate posting.) One more question - please: At that time I used Window's Paint and the image was scaled so small, but I just could not figure out how to make it centered. What software did you use? Thank you again and happy holidays.

Comment: I used [IrfanView](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrfanView) to clip the part of the picture. But I think that you should be able to copy part of a picture into clipboard in any decent software for displaying images. It is certainly possible in [MS Paint](http://www.google.com/search?q=ms+paint+crop).

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help.