# What would you do to resuscitate a fading posting?

Tags: discussion

I am currently a graduate student in an online program. Honestly, it is an understatement to say that I depend **so** much on this forum in finding like-minded people to engage in an intelligent discussion.

Whenever I got stuck on a problem, I would post it here and generally I would get feedback in less than one hour. Sometime, I was lucky to have my question explained in a very elaborate manner, complete with spoilers, that made my mind clicked instantly, just like the posting in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071240/mapping-normalizer-to-automorphism). But unfortunately not everyday is a rosy day for me, for some other times I got only spotty helps here and there for days and had to watch my posting faded into oblivion, even after my effort to resuscitate it with edits, just like my posting in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068944/what-is-a-simple-group).

> A little disclaimer - please: In posting this writing, it is **not** my intention to discredit any people who had tried helping me in the past. I am aware that each question has different merit, each person has different personality, writing style, time allowance, etc.

That being said, here are my questions:

(1) How do I jump-start my old question? Start a bounty? How does it work? Does it take away my reputation?  
(2) I understand that I am not allowed to re-post it for it will be labeled as duplicate, but if I re-post it in another forum, such as [Physics Forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/), am I running against any forum etiquette?  
(3) Just the other day I posted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18778/questions-about-inviting-response-dishonesty-uploading-image) the idea of "inviting" certain people, who I knew had demonstrated superior flair in explaining things, to look at my posting, but I was told it was not possible. Please let me know if you have any other suggestion.

Thank you very much for your time and help. Happy holidays!

**POST SCRIPT**: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
This posting is indeed a duplicate, for that I am glad to be reminded. Is there anybody have a say on (2)? Thank you again.

Comment: Bounties definitely help. Put a 50 rep bounty there; you can afford it. See [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: About the second point: You could have a look at older questions posted here at meta tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]).

Comment: Regarding 2: You are not violating any site etiquette by posting on a different website; be wary of cross posting on other Stack Exchange sites, though.